# Firebase query equalTo() or startAt().endAt() stop working

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I already tried suggestions from other posts but no success. 
I just run into an issue,I got the following code which displays data from Firebase database when user clicks on a specific date.If I comment out (startAt(),endAt()), the recycler gets populated with all data, when I add equalTo() or startAt().endAt()) recycler does not get populated.
The code before was working normally, just recently stopped working and I have no clue why.
The code looks like this:
Bellow is the adapter:

```
fun calendarAdapt(options:FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelCalendar>,dataref:  
 DatabaseReference,context: Context):FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelCalendar,CalendHold>{
    return object :FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelCalendar,CalendHold>(options){
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalendHold {
            return   
 CalendHold(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_row_calendar,parent,false))
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalendHold, positionc: Int, modelc: ModelCalendar) 
{

            val postkeyC= getRef(positionc).key
            dataref.child(postkeyC!!).addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    holder.bindlogC(modelc)
                 }
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Query:

```
 fun query2(cont: LifecycleOwner,selected_date:String):FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelCalendar>{
    val queryy = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .reference
        .child("Ev")
        .startAt(selected_date)
         .endAt(selected_date)

    return FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelCalendar>()
        .setQuery(queryy,ModelCalendar::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(cont)
        .build()
 }
```

Here I apply the adaptor:

```
  mDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Ev")
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year2 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month2 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day2 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val dayd= checkDigit(day2)
    val monthd= checkDigit(month2+1)
    val datetoday = java.lang.StringBuilder()
        .append(dayd)
        .append("-")
        .append(monthd)
        .append("-")
        .append(year2)
    calendinf(datetoday.toString())
    calendarid.setOnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
        val month = checkDigit(month+1)
        val day = checkDigit(dayOfMonth)
        val datesel =StringBuilder()
            .append(day)
            .append("-")
            .append(month)
            .append("-")
            .append(year)
        calendinf(datesel.toString())
         }
}
    private fun calendinf(selected_date:String){
    val options = Queryess().query2(this,selected_date)
    val adaptorC = Adaptall().calendarAdapt(options, mDb,this)
    calerec!!.adapter=adaptorC!!
}
```

Comment: There are too many variables in here. Can you reproduce the problem with a hardcoded value for `reftime`? So something like `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .reference
        .child("Ev")
        .equalTo("TheValueOfRefTime")`. If you can reproduce with that, please edit your question to include the simplified code.

Comment: edited, hope is more clear, I know that recommended reference for time should be with timestamp, tried also with timestamp same result.Also without querying startAt(time).endAt(time) recycle gets populated.  So looks like the problem stands on the query, but I don't understand what is wrong, and why suddenly stopped working

Comment: There's still a lot of string concatenation going on. If the problem is in your query, you should be able to reproduce it with hard-coded strings. If you can't reproduce it that way, the problem is probably in the rest of your code. Please also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Frank van Puffelen thank you for advice, is hard the code to be interpreted my I apologies for that. Anyway I fix-it,It was the query, was missing orderBychild() field, most probable I mistakenly deleted otherwise cannot explain-it :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix-it,It was the query, was missing "orderBychild()" field, most probable I mistakenly deleted otherwise cannot explain-it :))